# Angular Utils Pagination Directive not showing first page

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-directive

I am using [Angular Utils Pagination Directive](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)  in my app. Basically it works fine but problem is that when I filter table it doesn't show first page . For example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview) when I searched "meal 12" it hides the paging directive because it contains 1 record which is less than pagesize. I donot want to hide that instead it should show page1 . If filter is great than pagesize it works but when items less than pagesize it hides .

```
  <li dir-paginate="meal in meals | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" auto-hide="false">{{ meal }}</li>
```

I tried `auto-hide="false"` it doesnot work.

Need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an old version of the library, the version you have (at least, whats in your plunkr) doesn't support the auto-hide property.

Secondly, auto-hide is a setting for the controls, not the list, so you need to put it on the dir-pagination-controls element.

Comment: can you share any jsfiddle or plnk?